# Put limit in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

How can i put limit to something user does in one minute?
I have got this php code

```
 if(isset($_POST['new_post'])){
            $Text=htmlspecialchars($_POST['new_post'],ENT_QUOTES);
            $Text=trim($Text);
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Upload_f']['tmp_name'])) {
                    $fileP=$_FILES['Upload_f'];
                    $fileP_name=$fileP['name'];
                    $fileP_tmp=$fileP['tmp_name'];
                    $fileP_size=$fileP['size'];
                    $fileP_error=$fileP['error'];
                    $fileP_extension=explode('.', $fileP_name);
                    $fileP_extension=strtolower(end($fileP_extension));
                    $allowed=array('jpg','png');
                    if (in_array($fileP_extension, $allowed)){
                        if ($fileP_error===0) {
                            if ($fileP_size<=2097152){
                                $fileP_new_name=uniqid().'.'.$fileP_extension;  
                            }
                        }
                        $NotInarray=false;
                    }else{
                        $fileP_new_name="";  
                        $NotInarray=true;
                    }
                    $Fileuploaded=true;
            }else{
                $fileP_new_name="";
                $fileP=0;
                $Fileuploaded=false;
                $NotInarray=false;
            }
                $Posts=$con->query("SELECT Posts FROM user_opt WHERE Username='$NameId'");
                $row=$Posts->fetch_row();
            if (strlen($Text)>400) {
                $Res="Error occurred.Please try again";
                $PostNum=$row[0];
            }elseif(strlen($Text)==0 && $fileP==0){
                $Res="Both fields are empty";
                $PostNum=$row[0];
            }elseif($Fileuploaded===true){
                if ($NotInarray==true) {
                $Res="Only jpg and png files are allowed";
                $PostNum=$row[0];
                }elseif ($fileP_error!=0) {
                $Res="Error occurred.Please try again";
                $PostNum=$row[0];
                }else{
                    $Res="Success";
                    $PostNum=$row[0]+1;
                    $upladed++;
                }
            }else{
                    function generateRandomString($length) {
                        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
                        $randomString = '';
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
                        }
                        return $randomString;
                    }
                    $Rand=generateRandomString(100);
                    $query=$con->query("INSERT INTO uploads (Rand,Username,image,`Text`,`Date`) VALUES('$Rand','$NameId','$fileP_new_name','$Text',NOW())");
                    $querya=$con->query("UPDATE user_opt SET posts=posts+1 WHERE Username='$NameId'");
                    $PostNum=$row[0]+1;
                    $Res="Success";           
                    $upladed++;
                }
                 echo json_encode(array($Res,$PostNum,$upladed));
        }
```

This code is called by ajax.How can i make this code execute maximum 5 times in one minute?I have tried making it this way

```
    $upladed=0;
     if(isset($_POST['new_post'])){
            if ($upladed<=5) {
              code
  }
}
```

But every time new ajax comes $upladed becomes 0 again

Comment: You need to store the variable somewhere to be able to use it across requests, in session, in cache, etc.

Comment: @JimL How can i store it in cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the session to store the $uploaded variable's value, and retrieve it every time an Ajax call happens. You may also want to store the actual minute when the first post happened, to make sure that no more posts should arrive in THAT minute. And you should invalidate the $uploaded (set it to 0 ) when another minute is started.

More better if you are storing the actual second of the first post, and give 60 seconds to the other potential uploads (up to your limit)

The modified code could look like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

function generateRandomString($length) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function isFileUploadAllowed() {
    $isAllowed                  = true;
    $timeNow                    = time();
    $timeFrameInSeconds         = 60;
    $maxUploadsInTimeFrame      = 5;
    $firstUploadTime            = $_SESSION['firstUploadTime'] ? intval($_SESSION['firstUploadTime']) : $timeNow;
    $numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame = $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame'] ? intval($_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame']) : 0;
    $givenTimeFrameExpired      = (($firstUploadTime + $timeFrameInSeconds) < $timeNow);

    // when there would be more time to allow upload
    if (!$givenTimeFrameExpired) {
        // disallowing only when the limit is reached
        if ($numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame + 1 > $maxUploadsInTimeFrame) {
            $isAllowed = false;
        }
    }

    // if there is no need to restrict this upload
    if ($isAllowed === true) {
        // if previous time frame is expired, reset 'firstUploadTime' and 'numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame'
        if ($givenTimeFrameExpired) {
            $_SESSION['firstUploadTime'] = $timeNow;
            $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame'] = 0;
        }

        // increasing the number of uploaded files
        $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame']++;
    }

    return $isAllowed;
}

if(isset($_POST['new_post'])){
    $Text=htmlspecialchars($_POST['new_post'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $Text=trim($Text);
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Upload_f']['tmp_name'])) {
        if (isFileUploadAllowed()) {
            $fileP=$_FILES['Upload_f'];
            $fileP_name=$fileP['name'];
            $fileP_tmp=$fileP['tmp_name'];
            $fileP_size=$fileP['size'];
            $fileP_error=$fileP['error'];
            $fileP_extension=explode('.', $fileP_name);
            $fileP_extension=strtolower(end($fileP_extension));
            $allowed=array('jpg','png');
            if (in_array($fileP_extension, $allowed)){
                if ($fileP_error===0) {
                    if ($fileP_size<=2097152){
                        $fileP_new_name=uniqid().'.'.$fileP_extension;  
                    }
                }
                $NotInarray=false;
            }else{
                $fileP_new_name="";  
                $NotInarray=true;
            }
            $Fileuploaded=true;
        }
    }else{
        $fileP_new_name="";
        $fileP=0;
        $Fileuploaded=false;
        $NotInarray=false;
    }
        $Posts=$con->query("SELECT Posts FROM user_opt WHERE Username='$NameId'");
        $row=$Posts->fetch_row();
    if (strlen($Text)>400) {
        $Res="Error occurred.Please try again";
        $PostNum=$row[0];
    }elseif(strlen($Text)==0 && $fileP==0){
        $Res="Both fields are empty";
        $PostNum=$row[0];
    }elseif($Fileuploaded===true){
        if ($NotInarray==true) {
        $Res="Only jpg and png files are allowed";
        $PostNum=$row[0];
        }elseif ($fileP_error!=0) {
        $Res="Error occurred.Please try again";
        $PostNum=$row[0];
        }else{
            $Res="Success";
            $PostNum=$row[0]+1;
            $upladed++;
        }
    }else{
            $Rand=generateRandomString(100);
            $query=$con->query("INSERT INTO uploads (Rand,Username,image,`Text`,`Date`) VALUES('$Rand','$NameId','$fileP_new_name','$Text',NOW())");
            $querya=$con->query("UPDATE user_opt SET posts=posts+1 WHERE Username='$NameId'");
            $PostNum=$row[0]+1;
            $Res="Success";           
            $upladed++;
        }
         echo json_encode(array($Res,$PostNum,$upladed));
}
```

Comment: How can i store seconds in php?

Comment: So you can get it with the time() function. It gives you the current time as integer in seconds. Save it as: $_SESSION['firstUploadTime'] = time(); After you stored it into the session, you can always compare that with the actual time of the newer ajax calls.

Comment: Can u write the code in your answer i don't really know what u r talking about

Comment: I added a code example. I also moved outside your generateRandomString() function, in order to have some organization in your code. Just a suggestion: do not include function definitions inside any code like you did, more better if you start using OOP.

Comment: What should i add in index.php?

Comment: I don't know about your file names, so replace the code in that file where your code in the question is coming from.

Comment: Could you please include the new and whole file in your question? By the way, "not working at all" tells me nothing, you must be more specific.

Comment: Ok, I think some pieces were missing from your original solution, so I edited the sample code, please try again.

Comment: Thank you so much!